# What is meant by binary compatibility? What is its importance during serialization/deserialization in a language like Java that deals in byte code?

Tags: programming-languages, concepts, binary, serialization

In computing what is meant by *binary compatibility*?

I read about it in context of serialization/deserialization that this process of serialize/deserialize should be binary compatible. What does it mean in this context? In particular I am interested in understanding the role of binary compatibility in a language like Java that deals with byte code.

This quote is from Effective Java:

> When a serializable class is revised, it is important to check that
>   it is possible to serialize an instance in the new release and
>   deserialize it in old releases, and vice versa. The amount of testing
>   required is thus proportional to the product of the number of
>   serializable classes and the number of releases, which can be large.
>   These tests cannot be con-structed automatically because, in addition
>   to binary compatibility, you must test forsemantic compatibility. In
>   other words, you must ensure both that the
>   serialization-deserialization process succeeds and that it results in
>   a faithful replica of the original object. The greater the change to a
>   serializable class, the greater the need for testing. The need is
>   reduced if a custom serialized form is carefully designed when the
>   class is first written (Items 75, 78), but it does not vanish
>   entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just means the deserializer has to use the same binary format as the serializer did.  For example, consider serializing a string.  There are several different binary formats for a string, even though they represent the same data semantically.  One way is to first serialize a number representing the length of the string, then write the individual characters.  Another way is to just write out the characters and use a null character to signal the end of the string.

One serializer could use 16 bits to represent the length and one could use 32.  If it's a unicode string, one serializer could use UTF-8 encoding, one could use UTF-16 encoding, and one could write out a field specifying which encoding it is using in that particular instance.

That's just something as simple and commonplace as a string.  When you get to the object layer and higher, there are many more variations for how you can represent something in a binary stream.  If your serializer and deserializer aren't binary compatible, you'll get garbage out when you try to deserialize.

Sometimes the binary format will change over time, so a deserializer has to be aware of all previous formats in order to remain backwards compatible.  Serialized formats often include a version field for this express purpose.

Comment: Big endian and little endian also play into this.

Comment: @cschneid What role do they play ?

Comment: @Geek If you try serializing a 32 bit integer with a value of decimal 10 on a big endian machine by simply writing out the value in memory, you get x'0000000a' but on a little endian machine you get x'0a000000'.  If you want your serialization to be binary compatible across these different architectures you must have a mechanism to deal with the differences.  For example, you could choose to not store the in-memory representation but some character representation like "+10".

Comment: @cschneid excellent..Why don't you embellish the answer with your point. It is an extremely valid point since without taking this into account binary compatibility will fall flat.

Comment: @cschneid: I think Java's virtual machine is big endian, even when running on a little endian machine.  So, I'm not sure the endian-ness of a machine will impact Java serialization.